# DataGridView columns not showing same formatted date C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm querying data from SQL Server and getting below result in Management Studio.

[image: Query Result]

Now when I take the same result in a `DataTable`and assign that `DataTable` as a `DataSource` of `DataGridView` I'm getting below view.

[image: DataGridView]

`Last Updated On` showing correct format as SQL but `Initiated On` showing different one.

Method to retrieve data from SQL:

```
internal DataTable GetDGVData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_conStr))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDGVData_SP", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                connection.Open();
                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                connection.Close();
                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

DataSource assignment code:

```
var data = _dbOprations.GetDGVData();
if (data != null)
{
 //Assign datatable to DataGridView
 dgvTool.DataSource = data;
 //Hide Id column as not needed for user.
 dgvTool.Columns[0].Visible = false;
 //Refresh the DataGridView
 dgvTool.Refresh();
}
```

I haven't done any formatting to DataGridView control. Could someone spot the mistake I'm doing.

Comment: My guess is that your "Last Updated On" date is stored as text (likely `varchar`)

Comment: Have checked your Database to see whether those fields have the same data type (Date or String)? Anyway, you can re-define the presentation format for those columns.

Comment: @Rafalon you are correct. The data type for `Last Updated On` was varchar and `date` for `Initiated On`

Comment: @Jimi you are right. I missed the data type. Thank you.

Comment: If you change the Fields data type, choose Date for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type for `Last Updated On` was `varchar` and `date` for `Initiated On`. This was making that difference. Thanks [Rafalon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7831383/rafalon) and [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)